# Python / Selenium function call and required arguments missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have defined the following two functions:

```
def setUp(self, language):
    #defines the webdriver
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    #calls the website
    self.browser.get("http://www.test.com")

    #defines the language to be used
    self.INTERFACE_LANGUAGE = language
    if(language == "de"):
        self.username = "testDE@gmail.com"
        self.pwd = "test"
    elif(language == "en"):
        self.username = "testEN@gmail.com"
        self.pwd = "test"
    return self.username, self.pwd
```

and

```
def login_user(self, username, pwd):
    """login the user"""
    #fill in the userdata
    self.u_Name = self.browser.find_element_by_id("form_user_id")
    self.u_Name.send_keys(username)
    self.u_Pwd = self.browser.find_element_by_id("form_user_pwd")
    self.u_Pwd.send_keys(pwd)

    #submit the form
    self.submit_Login = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@name="send" and @value="Log in"]')
    self.submit_Login.click()
```

when I try to call setUp like this:

```
lang = "de"
username, pwd = setUp(lang)
login_user(username, pwd)
```

it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\test\test.py", line 40, in <module>
    username, pwd = setUp(lang)
TypeError: setUp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'language'
    login_user(username, pwd)
```

can someone help me please to fix this. I don't understand why it says that there is an argument missing.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `def setUp(self, language):` - two arguments, `= setUp(lang)` - one argument. That's why `setUp() missing 1 required positional argument`

Comment: The first argument of bound methods (i.e. self/cls/whatever you name it) is supplied implicitly, you do not explicitly pass it yourself.

Comment: it seems you took methods from class and now you use them as normal functions which don't need `self`. Or maybe you have wrong indentions in code and those function should be inside class.

Comment: @furas your solution did it for me!
Tahnks to all for the fast feedback!

Answer (score 0):

As @furas said, I was simply using the functions as they were in a class but they were not.

So the solution was to remove the self from the argument list:

```
def setUp(language):
    #defines the webdriver
    global browser, INTERFACE_LANGUAGE
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    #calls the website
    browser.get("http://www.test.com")

    #defines the language to be used
    INTERFACE_LANGUAGE = language
    if(language == "de"):
        username = "test"
        pwd = "test"
    elif(language == "en"):
        username = "test"
        pwd = "test"
    return username, pwd

def login_user(username, pwd):
    """login the user to their account"""
    #fill in the userdata
    u_Name = browser.find_element_by_id("form_user_id")
    u_Name.send_keys(username)
    u_Pwd = browser.find_element_by_id("form_user_pwd")
    u_Pwd.send_keys(pwd)

    #submit the form
    submit_Login = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@name="send" and @value="Log in"]')
    submit_Login.click()
```